# Version number error executing package with xp_cmdshell

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS package on Server2 (2008, 64 bit)and I am trying to call it from server1(2005, 32 bit) using xp_cmdshell using command,

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'dtexec /FILE "\\Wdvwd99a0234\PWOSSIS\RTS_SSIS\RTS_ETL.BE_2_DUNSMasterPackage.dtsx"'
```

It keeps giving error:

> Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility Version 9.00.5000.00
>   for 32-bit Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1984-2005. All rights
>   reserved. NULL Started:  1:00:42 PM Error: 2012-11-29 13:00:42.83
>   Code: 0xC001700A    Source:      Description: The version number in
>   the package is not valid. The version number cannot be greater than
>   current version number. End Error Error: 2012-11-29 13:00:42.83
>   Code: 0xC0016020    Source:      Description: Package migration from
>   version 3 to version 2 failed with error 0xC001700A "The version
>   number in the package is not valid. The version number cannot be
>   greater than current version number.". End Error Error: 2012-11-29
>   13:00:42.83    Code: 0xC0010018    Source:      Description: Error
>   loading value "3" from node
>   "DTS:Property". End Error Could not load package
>   "\Wdvwd99a0234\PWOSSIS\RTS_SSIS\RTS_ETL.BE_2_DUNSMasterPackage.dtsx"
>   because of error 0xC0010014. Description: The package failed to load
>   due to error 0xC0010014 "One or more error occurred. There should be
>   more specific errors preceding this one that explains the details of
>   the errors. This message is used as a return value from functions that
>   encoun ter errors.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.
>   Source:  Started:  1:00:42 PM Finished: 1:00:42 PM Elapsed:  0.078
>   seconds NULL

Comment: The error message says "The version number in the package is not valid. The version number cannot be greater than current version number." Since you are running a 2008 package with a 2005 tool, that should give you a clear hint as to the problem.

Comment: @Pondlife, so i cant use PSexec also?

Comment: As others have explained in more detail, you can't execute a 2008 package using a 2005 tool. It doesn't matter if you execute the tool using xp_cmdshell, PSexec or some other way, the tool itself is not compatible with the package.

Answer (score 3):

As others have commented, the version of dtexec.exe needs to match the version of the target package. Your options are

- Install the 2008 Integration Services components on Server1. You would need to provide an explicit path to the dtexec to ensure xp_cmdshell runs the 2008 version.
- Run the package on the remote (Server2) machine. Lowest barrier of entry would be to create a SQL Agent job on Server2, unscheduled, that simply runs the package `RTS_ETL.BE_2_DUNSMasterPackage.dtsx` You would then start the job in place of the current xp_cmdshell. `EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_start_job 'RTS_ETL.BE_2_DUNSMasterPackage'` Two caveats to this approach

  1. You can have as many concurrent dtexec calls running as your machine can support. A specific SQL Agent job cannot be running more than once.
  2. If you were providing dynamic run-time options, that also isn't going to work with an agent job.

Comment: if i try with psexec it opens the SSIS package from etl server but fails with error, can not get configuration details for all the connections.

Comment: What sort of configuration is the package using?

Comment: xml configuration and 2 database connection configuration

Answer (score 2):

A 2008 package cannot be ran with the 2005 package utility.